# JavaScript function seems to be undefined on runtime

Tags: javascript

Everything works well in my code except for the function "typewriter" that refuses to be not undefined on runtime.

```
function typewriter() {
      sContents = ""; //repeated though
      iRow = Math.max(0, iIndex - iScrollAt); //rhis only tries to see which is the largest number. if you solve iindex-iscrollat, you'd get -20. between -20 and zero, zero is bigger, so math.max picks it and it is now assigned to iRow. you can console.log iRow to check its value. i think it is better to just say iRow is equal to zero, instead of passing through the stress.
      var destination = document.getElementById("typed"); //get the element that it the array text would be appended to.

      while (iRow < iIndex) { //the while here is a type of loop, while the iRow is less than the position of the text in the array. execute the below code as long as the condition is true. this condition is only true when the iIndex has been moved to 1 or the next string. that means this code for the next text string after the first. tested with console.log(iRow, iIndex);
        sContents += aText[iRow] + "<br>"; //mind you, increment of zero is 1.
        iRow++;
      }

      destination.innerHTML = sContents + aText[iIndex].substring(0, iTextPos) + blinky.innerHTML; //this code will run first for the first string text ie iIndex equal to 0. then it will run a second time, but this time it will add the next steing text to the first one, which will make them stay in the same element called destination it was tested with this "console.log(sContents);" 

      //the substring starts from 0, thats first character and returns the following characters as iTextPos increments. one by one.
      if (iTextPos++ == iArrLength) { //the heart of the code. this says if the increment in the textposition is equal to the length of the text in that particular string. it won't work if iTextpos++ is put as iTextpos, because it is always incrementing. check this out to see "console.log(iTextPos);"
        iTextPos = 0; //text position is reseted here.blinky.style.borderRight = "10px solid white"; //to show itself
        blinky.style.display = "inline"; //very important, to make it inline with the text which i alredy made display as inline too, in order for them to appear on same line together.
        iIndex++; //iIndex is incremented, and thats what causes iIndex to turn to 1 meaning next line, if theres another, it will turn to 2 and so on.
        if (iIndex != aText.length) { //it will almost likely never be equal to it, so the below code will always run.
          iArrLength = aText[iIndex].length; //the iArrLength is updated with new length for new string or next string.
          setTimeout("typewriter()", 500); //function is then called again after 500ms, so as to render the next text out.
        }
      }
      else {
        setTimeout("typewriter()", iSpeed); //if no new line, call function after iSpeed value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything not defined there are defined in my environment.

**The problem**: the`typewriter()` doesn't call the function `typewriter()` . It just end up being undefined in console. I don't think I have any typo in the code (not the comments though).

Comment: I believe when you use the string form of setTimeout(), the text in the "code to run" argument gets evaluated in the global context, not in the context where setTimeout is called. So calling typewriter() doesn't see your typewriter function, because it's a nested function inside xbot. If this is the problem, using the callback form rather than the string form (as General Grievance suggest) should fix it.

Comment: In other words: `setTimeout(typewriter, iSpeed);`

Comment: In even other words, use a function ***reference*** (no quotes or parenthesis) instead of a function ***call*** (with parenthesis) as a string.

Comment: The vast majority of the code is not needed for a [mcve]. It just gets in the way of properly describing the issue. https://jsbin.com/gofilapofu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the function as a string to setTimeout (like you do with `setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);`), you need to pass the function itself like this: `setTimeout(typewriter, 500);`. Same goes for the other setTimeout: `setTimeout(typewriter, iSpeed);`.

Why can't you use a string here? Because, as mentioned in the comments, using a string instead of passing a function will run the string in the [global scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), and since `typewriter` is defined inside of another function, it will be inaccessible from the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super well versed in closures, but I think that your code is failing due to `setTimeout` creating a closure when it gets called initially (before the timeout occurs).  This makes a context where your function doesn't exist yet (I think).  You can get around this by using the other syntax of setTimeout, where you give it a callback function without invoking it.  So instead of

```
setTimeout("typewriter()", 500);
```

try

```
setTimeout(typewriter, 500);
```

Below I threw together two functions, one using your current syntax and one with my suggested syntax

```js
myFunc(10)

// works
function myFunc(num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    console.log(num)
    setTimeout(() => myFunc(num - 1), 500)
  }
}

myOtherFunc(10)

// doesn't work
function myOtherFunc(num) {
  if (num > 0) {
    console.log(num)
    setTimeout('myOtherFunc(num - 1)', 500)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is less about closures and more about Global scope. For practical purposes, a closure is created when a nested function outlives its parent and must retain access to the parent scope. Here, because of the string syntax used, the callback is being executed in the Global scope and the function to be called can't be directly accessed from that scope.

Comment: Great, I could see the error on mine!